# How to sleep the following thread for 5 minutes after running once for 60 seconds

Tags: java, multithreading

```
  ScheduledExecutorService blinkRate = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        blinkRate.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               if(blink_count < 10 && blink_count > 0){
                  //sleep the thread for 10 minutes
               } 
            }
        }, 0, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to put threads to sleep inside a thread pool. Think about why you want to do this. If it is related to the tasks available then it would be better to throttle the tasks you put into the pool. Or you could have a global condition object that the threads in the pool could wait on and you decide when you need to notify the threads. But this would make performance worse. The first option is usually the better choice

Comment: If you want to vary the delay, you probably shouldn't be using scheduleAtFixedRate.  Considering using a [DelayQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html) instead.

Comment: Looks like you want a task to be invoked at varying intervals in some repeating pattern.  I would not try to do that with a _fixed rate_ scheduler.  Instead, I would create an object that always knows when the next invocation of the task is due, and then I would have each invocation of the task use that object to explicitly schedule the next invocation.